# Create view on Redshift for performance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, tableview, aws-glue

I am facing for creating view to redshift with data from glue (S3), my case is:

I have three tables data (millions records) from S3 for glue:

- table A
- table B
- table C

I have a query that:

(group by day table A) join (group by day table B) join (group by day table C)

So, I have 3 options:

- Option 1:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW VVV AS
(group by day table A) join (group by day table B) join (group by day table C)
```

then query from VVV

- Option 2:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V1 AS
(group by day table A)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V2 AS
(group by day table B)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V3 AS
(group by day table C)
```

Then query from V1 join V2 join V3

- Option 3:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V1 AS
(table A)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V2 AS
(table B)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V3 AS
(table C)
```

Then query from (group by day V1) join (group by day V3) join (group by day V3)

So I don't know what is the best for performance

Comment: Try them all and then measure the performance. Let us know what you find! You could also try `explain select * from <view name>` and see the [Query plan - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html). That will give an indication of relative performance.

Comment: MySQL does not recognize `MATERIALIZED`.  The general answer for MySQL is "don't even consider VIEWs".  Removing tag.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a materialized view is in precomputing the results of an expensive query at the expense of potentially out of date values. To maximize this value I suspect that doing the most work as part of the materialized view will be best - option 1.

Just remember to refresh materialized views regularly and if you are refreshing your views for every use then you shouldn't be using materialized views. These are for computing once and using the results many times